# Passenger Rack app 'cannot infer basepath'

Tags: ruby, passenger, rack, sinatra

I have a simple `config.ru` file for my Sinatra app.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'app'

run Sinatra::Application
```

However, Passenger is failing with the error `no such file to load -- app`. I've tried using the 1.9 method `require_relative` but that now causes the error `cannot infer basepath`.

I'm currently using the very hacky `require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'app' )`, which is just horrible and I don't fancy doing that every time I want to require a file.

Is there any reason why Ruby isn't acting as usual?

Comment: Would this question not be more appropriate on our sister site stackoverflow.com, it's where coding related questions are usually asked? I can move it over for you if you wish, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby 1.9.2 the current directory is no more in LOAD_PATH.

So what if your LOAD_PATH and add current_directory if is not made.

Comment: I didn't know that. Interesting. However, I still don't understand why `require_relative` wouldn't work.

Comment: Or I can just `require "./app"` which seems easier.

Comment: Yes, it's same thing about the current_directory no in LOAD_PATH

Comment: Can someone explain this answer better? All I know is using require "./app" worked for me, but I don't understand why. Has ruby changed fundamentally in 1.9.2?

Comment: A rackup file is not Ruby, it is a DSL which is similar to Ruby and not all ruby works in a .ru file.  `require_relative` uses the callstack to determine the location of the file being required, and because the contents of a .ru are eval'd the callstack isn't helpful enough. See:
https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/115
https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/244