# Capistrano: require_relative does not work as expected

Tags: ruby, capistrano

Suppose the following Rails setup:

- Rails 3.2.9
- Capistrano 2.13.5
- Using the multistage extension (i.e. capistrano/ext/multistage)
- A production stage defined, e.g. in `Rails.root/config/deploy/production.rb`.

Inside production.rb, you *cannot* use require_relative, it seems — you end up getting the 'cannot infer basepath' error. However, if you just plain `ruby production.rb`, the require_relative works fine.

Why is this the case? It seems that Capistrano loads/executes the code in such a way to make require_relative not work as expected.

I suspect this is similar to: [Passenger Rack app 'cannot infer basepath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811781/passenger-rack-app-cannot-infer-basepath), which (roughly speaking) suggests that require_relative can fail depending on how the code is ultimately loaded/run.

The source for require_relative in branch ruby_1_9_3 is given below, and it shows how require_relative depends on the call stack. However, the end-to-end picture is not complete — how Capistrano finds and executes code, and how that affects the call stack.

I don't think anything here is unsolvable, but in lieu of time to dig into this problem myself, any expert insight as to what's going on would be much appreciated, not only for the specific issue but for the insight into how Cap and Ruby work.

```
// load.c
VALUE
rb_f_require_relative(VALUE obj, VALUE fname)
{
    VALUE base = rb_current_realfilepath();
    if (NIL_P(base)) {
        rb_raise(rb_eLoadError, "cannot infer basepath");
    }   
    base = rb_file_dirname(base);
    return rb_require_safe(rb_file_absolute_path(fname, base), rb_safe_level());
}

// vm_eval.c
VALUE
rb_current_realfilepath(void)
{
    rb_thread_t *th = GET_THREAD();
    rb_control_frame_t *cfp = th->cfp;
    cfp = vm_get_ruby_level_caller_cfp(th, RUBY_VM_PREVIOUS_CONTROL_FRAME(cfp));
    if (cfp != 0) return cfp->iseq->filepath;
    return Qnil;
}
```

Comment: I can't help with Rails/Capistrano. Before `require_relative` I have added `p method(:require_relative).owner`. The output is Kernel. Can you check it to see if require_relative has been redefined ?

Answer (score 1):

http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9 says :

> Requires a library whose path is relative to the file containing the
>   call. Thus, if the directory /usr/local/mylib/bin contains the file
>   myprog.rb and that program contains the following line:
>   require_relative "../lib/mylib" then Ruby will look for mylib in
>   /usr/local/mylib/lib.

If I have such a directory structure :

```
a/b/c/d1
a/b/c/d2
a/b/c/d2/e/f1
a/b/c/d2/e/f2

$ pwd
a/b/c/d1
$ ruby -w ../d2/e/f1/test_req_rel
```

File `a/b/c/d2/e/f1/test_req_rel.rb` contains :

```
require_relative '../f2/req1'
```

so it will search in `a/b/c/d2/e/f2`, because the call is in `a/b/c/d2/e/f1/test_req_rel.rb` and 
`'../f2/req1'` means back from `f1` to `e`, then forward in `f2`, where `req1.rb` must exist, or else you get the error "no such file to load -- /a/b/c/c/d/e (LoadError)"

(tested with Ruby 1.9.2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I revised the question quite heavily, so please take a look at the new version if you're still interested.